# Pandas Dataframe to dictionary of dictionaries of lists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I have this a dataframe like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | 1 | 1 |
| US | 1 | 2 |
| US | 2 | 1 |
| NL | 1 | 1 |
| US | 2 | 2 |
| DK | 1 | 1 |

and I would like to get a dictionary of dictionaries of lists grouped by col1, like that:

```
dict = {US: {1: [1, 2], 2: [1, 2]}, NL: {1: [1]}, DK: {1: [1]}}
```

Basically, each unique element of col1 should correspond to a nested dictionary that has the unique element of col2 as key and all the elements of col3 as values.

I tried

```
dct = df.groupby("col1").apply(lambda x: x.set_index("col2")['col2'].to_dict()).to_dict()
```

but I do not get the expected outcome.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option using a nested `groupby`:

```
out = df.groupby('col1').apply(lambda g: g.groupby('col2')['col3'].agg(list).to_dict()).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'DK': {1: [1]}, 'NL': {1: [1]}, 'US': {1: [1, 2], 2: [1, 2]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

### `itertuples`

```
d = {}
for a, b, c in df.itertuples(index=False, name=None):
    d.setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, []).append(c)

d

{'US': {1: [1, 2], 2: [1, 2]}, 'NL': {1: [1]}, 'DK': {1: [1]}}
```

---

Same thing but using `map` and `zip`

```
d = {}
for a, b, c in zip(*map(df.get, ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])):
    d.setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, []).append(c)

d

{'US': {1: [1, 2], 2: [1, 2]}, 'NL': {1: [1]}, 'DK': {1: [1]}}
```

---

### Pandas variants

I don't think these are as good as the method above

#### 1

```
d = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].agg(list)
{a: d.xs(a).to_dict() for a in d.index.levels[0]}

{'DK': {1: [1]}, 'NL': {1: [1]}, 'US': {1: [1, 2], 2: [1, 2]}}
```

#### 2

```
{
    a: b.xs(a).to_dict()
    for a, b in df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].agg(list).groupby('col1')
}

{'DK': {1: [1]}, 'NL': {1: [1]}, 'US': {1: [1, 2], 2: [1, 2]}}
```